# ¿Cómo comparar el promedio de una matriz con el promedio de cada fila?

Tags: java

que pena como hago para comparar el promedio de una matriz con el promedio de cada una de sus filas ?
tengo hecho el siguiente método

mi pensado es meter cada uno de los promedios de las filas en un ArrayList y comparar con el valor del promedio y tambien tengo un metodo para imprimir el array pero no se que estoy haciendo mal y si me pueden dar una idea de como hacerlo gracias.

```
  ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList();
    int promedio = Promedio(matriz1);   //ya tengo declarada una matriz1
    public void PromedioFilas(int matriz[][]) {

        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            sumF1 += matriz[0][j];
            promF1 = sumF1 / col;
            sumF2 += matriz[1][j];
            promF2 = sumF2 / col;
            sumF3 += matriz[2][j];
            promF3 = sumF3 / col;
            sumF4 += matriz[3][j];
            promF4 = sumF4 / col;
            sumF5 += matriz[4][j];
            promF5 = sumF5 / col;
            sumF6 += matriz[5][j];
            promF6 = sumF6 / col;
            sumF7 += matriz[6][j];
            promF7 = sumF7 / col;
            sumF8 += matriz[7][j];
            promF8 = sumF8 / col;
            sumF9 += matriz[8][j];
            promF9 = sumF9 / col;
            sumF10 += matriz[9][j];
            promF10 = sumF10 / col;
            sumF11 += matriz[10][j];
            promF11 = sumF11 / col;
            sumF12 += matriz[11][j];
            promF12 = sumF12 / col;
           
            
            a.add(0, promF1);
            a.add(1, promF2);
            a.add(3, promF3);
            a.add(4, promF4);
            a.add(5, promF5);
            a.add(6, promF6);
            a.add(7, promF7);
            a.add(8, promF8);
            a.add(9, promF9);
            a.add(10, promF10);
            a.add(11, promF11);
            a.add(12, promF12);
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El siguiente código calcula el promedio por fila y lo guarda en un arreglo. Luego se puede iterar el arreglo `promedio` para hacer las comparaciones, en la posición `promedio[0]` estará el valor de la fila 0 y así.

```
    // arreglo para guardar los promedios
    // uno por cada fila
    int[] promedios = new int[matriz.length];
    
    // for externo itera las filas de la matriz
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        // for interno itera las columnas
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
            // sumar todos los valores de la fila
            promedios[i] += matriz[i][j];
        }
        // divivir el valor de la suma de los valores entre el total de valores
        promedios[i] /= matriz[i].length;
    }
```